# Facebook API Page : get total likes, total comments and total posts likes

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to get the total likes of a page, total comments & total likes from posts (summarized).
I'm able to get the total likes of a page with the query:

```
{page_id}/?fields=fan_count
```

But I don't know how to get the total likes & comments from all posts summarized.
I'm looking for something like:

Page ID 10202

- 1029 Page likes
- 293 Page Posts comments
- 2933 Page Posts likes

I know that if I execute the query:

```
{page_id}/posts?fields=message,likes.limit(1).summary(true)
```

It will return me all the posts in that page with the total likes, but I don't want to loop through all the posts to know how much likes/comments I have.

Comment: You can check if any of the page insights metrics can delivers those values you want, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/insights/

Comment: @CBroe I'm aware of that but always returns empty (no data whatsoever)

Comment: Got the necessary permissions, used a page access token?

Comment: @CBroe yes, without Page Access Token i'm not even allowed to request the URL.